# How to resolve duplicate parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, url

I have an Ajax select input that changes the URL when changed, the page does not refresh. However when the select input is changed multiple times, repeated parameters stack in the URL:

> [domain]/find.php?cat=1#pricemin=10&pricemax=500#pricemin=10&pricemax=500

How can I use javascript to encode it back to:

> [domain]/find.php?cat=1#pricemin=10&pricemax=500

so that there are no duplicate parameters?

An example of my current jQuery is as below:

```
$('#filterform select').on('change', function(e){
        var dummy = $('#filterform').serialize(),
            loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0];

        someajaxfunction();//do ajax function here
        if(history.pushState){
            history.pushState(null, null, loc +'#'+ dummy);
        }
    });
```

I have tried replacing `loc` with `loc.pathname` and the repeated parameters problem is solved. However my `?cat=1` form parameter is gone as well which is not desired. I wish to look at this problem with a URL search-and-modify jQuery/javascript method, for example:

What we have is

> [domain]/find.php?cat=1&subcats%5B%5D=1&subcats%5B%5D=2

What we want is

> [domain]/find.php?cat=1&subcats=1+2

Is it possible?

**Note:** 5 minutes after posting this question I realised that using `loc.pathname + loc.search` solves my problem, sorry for the long post. I am still curious about a URL search-and-modify jQuery/javascript method. Would appreciate if anyone can provide a starting point, thanks!

Comment: You never really wanted '#' in there, did you?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 # is needed for some other functionality, but you are right, in this example I wish to know how to modify the URL with javascript, thats all ;)

Comment: I guess it's valid, just a little odd to see query string stuff the wrong side of a `#`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 You're right, as good practice I should change that. My main reason for doing so is to seperate form submission parameters and ajax parameters, you think I should put them together? If so, do I need to make sure it is separated by some special character or is '[domain]/find.php?cat=1&pricemin=10&pricemax=500' fine?

Comment: I see what you're doing now and can't say you're wrong to do so. But more conventionally, you would retain state-related data by passing a js plain object to `history.pushState()` as its first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function removeDuplicate(url) {
  url = decodeURIComponent(url);                  // decode the url, %5B becomes [ and ,%5D becomes ]. Hence the url becomes  [domain]/find.php?cat=1&subcats[]=1&subcats[]=2
  var query = url.split('?')[1];                  // get only the query
  var parts = query.split('&');                   // split the query into parts: cat=1, subcats[]=1, subcats[]=2
  var params = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var nv = parts[i].split('=');
    if (!nv[0]) continue;
    var value = nv[1] || true;
    if (params[nv[0]] && params[nv[0]].indexOf(value)) {
      params[nv[0]].push(value);
    } else {
      params[nv[0]] = [value];
    }
  }

  url = url.split('?')[0] + '?';
  var keys = Object.keys(params);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    url += keys[i] + '=' + params[keys[i]].join('+');

    if (i !== keys.length - 1) url += '&';
  }
  return url;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I understand that you mean the php needs the [] for form submission, you do also mean that it is impossible to change the URL somehow after the the form submission?

Comment: Actually I am not sure what the [] is used for in this case. It looks like there is something missing in the url. What I mean in the answer is that, logically, `subcats=1&subcats=2` is not  equivalent to `subcats=1+2` so there is no way to do what you ask for. FYI, I think removing duplicate parameters is dangerous. As you can see `subcats=1&subcats=2` is redundant to `subcats=2`. While the first is always false, the later might be true in cases.

Comment: [] is used by PHP as a proper way to serialize form variables (it's weird I know), for example, multiple checkboxes. I understand where you are coming from, but in this case, logically they are equivalent.

Comment: @iWillGetBetter, I have just realized that by `subcats=1+2` you mean `subcats = 1 or 2`. I thought it was `subcats=3`. I modified it so that it works just like what you ask for

Comment: thanks! just to push you a bit more, because you started with a fixed string, does your solution still work when you need to get the URL after a page load/ajax submission?